# Uploading HEX file to Arduino

Tags: arduino, hex

I have an Arduino Nano board and I use mikroPascal as my development IDE
For uploading I currently use XLoader, but it is not possible to use that software with commandline parameters so I can integrate it in my IDE.
What I am looking for is some software that can upload my HEX file using the bootloader on the Arduino board using commandline parameters so that I just press a key combo in the IDE and then the file is uploaded and the uploader software shuts down agin.
Hope this makes sense.

Update:
I have done some further experimenting and have found some hint on the web

I have come up with a commandline that says 
AVRDUDE.EXE -c arduino -p atmega328 -P com8 -b 57600 -vv -U flash:w:"D:\Documents\mikroPascal\Stoker\MyStokerSlave.hex":i
but I get the error saying
AVRDUDE.EXE: Can't find programmer id "arduino"

This puzzles me a bit since I have the XLoader utility running from the same folder using the same AVRDUDE config and that works OK. But as I said from start I want to add it to my mikroPascal IDE and that is no possible with XLoader

Answer (score 0):

The de facto command line programmer for AVR-based Arduinos is [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/).

Comment: OK - that I will have to take a look at and see what it can do for me

Comment: Have you any idea as to what programmer to select for it to work with the Arduino boards?

Comment: Google says "arduino" for the Nano.

Comment: AVRDUDE.EXE: Can't find programmer id "arduino"

Comment: In fact stk500v1 is the correct value to use with Arduino Nano

Answer (score 0):

I work with following command,
avrdude -C./avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -b57600 -cstk500v1 -PCOM6 -D -Uflash:w:Blink.ino.hex:i

Comment: Looks a lot like the result I came to and got working.  I have wriiten a small GUI in Delphi for the AVR dude so that i can use it from my developement IDE mikroPascal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ArduinoSketchUploader](https://github.com/christophediericx/ArduinoSketchUploader) to do this.

*(Disclaimer: this is a library + command line utility I personally wrote.)*

Usage would be something like this:

```
ArduinoSketchUploader.exe --file=C:\MyHexFile\myHexFile.hex --port=COM3 --model=NanoR3
```